# MPI_Bcast one of proces does not recive

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a problem with mpi_Bcast. I want to sent an array of calculate how many numbers are per process to another process and the random process don't recive anything and crash(the process rank 2 and last-1).The number per process can be differ aboout 1. Can anybody help my ?

```
#include <stdio.h>          // printf
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>         
#include <time.h>  
#include <iostream>
#include "EasyBMP.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int* per_process = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            per_process[i] = 0;
        }

    if (rank == 0){


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            int default_for_process = 12 / size;
            int rest = 12 % size;

            if (i < rest){
                default_for_process++;

            }
            per_process[i] = default_for_process;
        }

    }


    MPI_Bcast(&per_process, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout <<rank<<" "<< per_process[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the `&` in `MPI_Bcast(&per_process, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` to have `MPI_Bcast(per_process, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` and that should work much better

Comment: Unsolicited advice: There is no need to use `MPI_Bcast` at all. Each rank can compute the entire `per_process[]` array on its own as its values depend only on `size` and that is known to all ranks.

Comment: I know but in this exercise i need to use BCAST

Comment: Did removing the `&` solve your issue?

Comment: Yes! I remove & befor per_process and its work fine :) Thanks Gilles !